# WCF message body showing <s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body> after modification

Tags: wcf

Trying to use MessageInspector to modify the message before the wcf service through the proxy. However while debugging the message body does not gets copied and body shows

```
 <s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body>
```

What is the problem with the code?

```
public class CustomWCFMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        request = ModifyMessage(request);
        return null;
    }

    private Message ModifyMessage(Message oldMessage)
    {
        Message newMessage = null;
        MessageBuffer msgbuf = oldMessage.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

        Message tmpMessage = msgbuf.CreateMessage();
        XmlDictionaryReader xdr = tmpMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents();

        XDocument xd = ConvertToXDocument(xdr);

        EmitTags(xd);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
        xd.Save(xw);

        xw.Flush();
        xw.Close();

        ms.Position = 0;
        XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(ms);

        newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(tmpMessage.Version, null, xr);
        newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(tmpMessage);
        newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(tmpMessage.Properties);

        return newMessage;
    }
```

}

Comment: Looks like .ToString() is being called on the body ...

Comment: What does ConvertToXDocument look like? perhaps it is calling xdr.ToString()

Comment: Is there any problem with the ToString(). You are right ToString is called in ConvertToXDocument.   XDocument ConvertToXDocument(XmlDictionaryReader xdr)
        {
            XNode xn = XNode.ReadFrom(xdr);
            string s = xn.ToString();
            return XDocument.Parse(s);
        }

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that the newMessage body was not shown in the watch window after doing ToString()

Created the buffered copy of the message to be shown in the debugger.

```
MessageBuffer messageBuffer = newMessage.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
Message message = messageBuffer.CreateMessage();
```

So there is **No problem** in the code. It is just that the debugger is not showing the message body as mentioned in the link below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675(v=VS.90).aspx

in the **Accessing the Message Body** for Debugging section.

Answer (score 29):

Here is solution:
if you call Message.ToString() you will get

> ..stream..

Instead use System.Xml.XmlWriter. Here is a sample:

```
MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
Message msg = buffer.CreateMessage();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (System.Xml.XmlWriter xw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb))
{
    msg.WriteMessage(xw);
    xw.Close();
}
Console.WriteLine("Message Received:\n{0}", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: It seems that you also have to call `buffer.CreateMessage()` again and assign it to the original request ref that's being passed in. The request can only be read once, so if you don't do this you'll get an error. Other than that though, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect ToString will return what you are getting. ToString is often used for debugging, and hence only shows you basic information about the object. You need to do something like this in ConvertToXDocument:

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Load(xdr);
```

Comment: ToString() is returning the body properly. XDocument.Load(xdr); is throwing some exception "The XmlReader state should be EndOfFile after this operation." While debugging the variable xd returns value propery, however after the EmitTags() something is going wrong.

Comment: Strange ... perhaps all is not as it seems. Maybe you only *think* the message content is wrong because that is how the debugger reports it, when in reality its ok

Comment: How exactly are you getting  <s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body>?

Comment: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <s:Header> <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="XYZ">XYZ</Action> </s:Header> <s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body> </s:Envelope>