# XmlDictionaryReader changes the xml namespace alias

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have following XML Input for a WCF service. Using XmlReader I am validating the message and replaces with a new message. During this process the xml namespace alias is changed from `xmlns:soapenv` to `xmlns:s`

What change need to be done in the following C# code in order to maintain the namespace alias while recreating the message?

Refer [WCF message body showing <s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body> after modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106196/wcf-message-body-showing-sbody-stream-sbody-after-modification) for viewing the correct replaced message content.

From [WCF Extensibility – Message Inspectors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/23/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx)

> WCF Message objects can only be “consumed” once – and “consumed” can mean read, written or copied. The message body is essentially a read-once stream, so once it’s consumed it cannot be used again. So if, in the inspector code, one were to read the message, the WCF runtime wouldn’t be able to reuse that message in the rest of its pipeline (i.e., to encode it to send as a reply or to parse it into operation parameters). So if the inspector code needs to read the message, it’s the responsibility of the inspector to recreate the message.

**Input**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header>
<To soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://local:54956/Service1.svc</To>
<Action soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</Action>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:GetData>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:value>4</tem:value>
  </tem:GetData>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**CODE**

```
 private void MyInspectorsValidateMessageBody(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, bool isARequest)
    {

        string originalMessageText = message.ToString();

        if (!message.IsFault)
        {
            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
            XmlReader bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadSubtree();

            //Settings
            XmlReaderSettings wrapperSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            wrapperSettings.CloseInput = true;
            wrapperSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None;
            wrapperSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            //Add a event handler for ValidationEventHandler of XmlReaderSettings
            //Validation happens while read of xml instance
            //wrapperSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(MyHandlerForXMLInspectionErrors);

            XmlReader wrappedReader = XmlReader.Create(bodyReader, wrapperSettings);

            this.isRequest = isARequest;

            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlDictionaryWriter xdw = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(memStream);
            xdw.WriteNode(wrappedReader, false);
            xdw.Flush(); memStream.Position = 0;

            XmlDictionaryReader xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(memStream, quotas);

            //Reconstruct the message with the validated body
            Message replacedMessage = Message.CreateMessage(message.Version, null, xdr);
            replacedMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(message.Headers);
            replacedMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(message.Properties);
            message = replacedMessage;

            string replacedMessageText = replacedMessage.ToString();

        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://local:54956/Service1.svc</To>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it's not changing the namespace. It's changing the prefix used to *refer* to the namespace, but in both cases the namespace itself is `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`.

From the original document:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
```

And from the output:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Nothing *should* care what prefix is being used - it's the URI of the actual namespace which is important.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But I need to maintain the `alias`. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Lijo: *Why* - what's going to care? Whatever it is is broken IMO.

Comment: I have a custom validation that checks for presence of xmlns:soapenv.

Comment: @Lijo: Well stop doing that. Instead, validate the presence of elements with the appropriate URI. Why would you want to claim that documents are invalid when they *are* actually valid, but happen to use a different prefix? If your validation is broken, you should fix the validation rather than changing other things to comply with the brokenness.

Comment: I shall consider fixing the logic. However I would like to know why it got changed. I have a different version of this inspector (used in other projects) that maintain the namespace alias. Any idea how we can force the alias to be same?

Comment: @Lijo: No, I don't know how you can force them to be the same - but I personally wouldn't waste any effort on it. The prefix is meant to be incidental, so make sure it is in the code using it, basically.