# Re-writing WCF Message using IClientMessageInspector

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, soap

I am calling a vendor web service and the schema of their calls requires custom namespaces in the body tag like this:

```
<s:Body xmlns:ddw="http://www.infinity.com/bpm/model/OmniLinkServices/DDWEBCallInput" 
        xmlns:omn="http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices">
```

I could not find a good way via attribute configurations, binding configurations, etc to add this namespace, so I created an implementation of IClientMessageInspector to add the namespaces to the body tag.  It works, but then the body of the message becomes:

```
<s:Body xmlns:ddw="http://www.infinity.com/bpm/model/OmniLinkServices/DDWEBCallInput" 
   xmlns:omn="http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices">
   ... stream ...
</s:Body>
```

Note the odd ... stream ... contents of the body.

This is my implementation of `BeforeSendRequest` on `IClientMessageInspector`

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
        //Copy old message into XPathNavigator so as first step in transforming it to (newer) XDocument for modification
        Message newMessage = null;
        MessageBuffer msgbuf = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        XPathNavigator nav = msgbuf.CreateNavigator();

        //load the old message into message stream via XmlWriter
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
        nav.WriteSubtree(xw);
        xw.Flush();
        xw.Close();
        ms.Position = 0;

        //load the XDocument from the XmlREader
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(ms));
        ms.Close();

        //add the sungard namespaces to the body of the message
        var body = (from x in xDoc.Descendants() where x.Name.LocalName == "Body" select x).First();
        var ddwns = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ddw", "http://www.infinity.com/bpm/model/OmniLinkServices/DDWEBCallInput");
        var omnns = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "omn", "http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices");
        body.Add(ddwns);
        body.Add(omnns);

        //create the new message
        //write the XDoc back out to memory stream
        MemoryStream newMsg = new MemoryStream();
        xw = XmlWriter.Create(newMsg);            
        xDoc.Save(xw);
        xw.Flush();
        xw.Close();
        newMsg.Position = 0;

        //create the new message        
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(newMsg);
        newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
        request = newMessage;
        return null;
}
```

At the very end of the function, the `XDocument` still has valid XML, but when I create the message at the end, that seems to be where the problem occurs.

Anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106196/wcf-message-body-showing-sbody-stream-sbody-after-modification) of any use?

Comment: Well that's annoying.  I was getting the message from the WCF logs, but when I look through fiddler at the complete message I'm seeing the right XML, i.e. not the ... stream ...   Why would WCF log that way?  What a waste of half a day :)  Thanks @barrick for pointing me to that link b/c the link said the same thing which made me look at fiddler.

Comment: @jeff.enyon No problem. From memory, try setting the `transferMode` on the `<binding>` in the *.config to `buffered`. The `...stream...` appears because the message is being streamed - potentially in chunks - through WCF and so it can't be certain that it has the whole message at any point, and obviously saving the chunks in memory so as to be able to get at the entire message afterwards is effectively buffering and then the advantages of streaming have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is just the way WCF was logging the message.  Looking at fiddler the entire xml is going through.  I don't understand why WCF would log this way but whatever.

FYI for anybody else who runs into this.