# .Net System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(...) not writing body

Tags: wcf, soap, c#-4.0

I am trying to write some unit tests for a SOAP Router that I have created and need to sent a Message to the system under test that has specific values in the body that are being checked.

I am able hit the system under test but the result is always false.

Below is the code that I am using to try and build up the message

```
public Message CreateValidGetProposalListMessage()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:exsl=\"http://exslt.org/common\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">");
    sb.AppendLine("  <s:Header xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
    sb.AppendLine("    <To s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">https://localhost:44321/routingService</To>");
    sb.AppendLine("    <Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">getList</Action>");
    sb.AppendLine("  </s:Header>");
    sb.AppendLine("  <soapenv:Body>");
    sb.AppendLine("    <getList xmlns=\"http://xxx">");
    sb.AppendLine("      <code>xxx</code>");
    sb.AppendLine("    </getList>");
    sb.AppendLine("  </soapenv:Body>");
    sb.AppendLine("</soapenv:Envelope>");

    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));

    var xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
    var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(xdr, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);

    return newMessage;
}
```

With this code the message is created, however the body always returns like this

```
  <soapenv:Body>... stream ...</soapenv:Body>
```

I have a total of 9 tests that I need to write to complete the test conditions and am failing on the first because the body of the message is not being written.

I appreciate this might not be the correct approach and would be grateful if anyone could help me get this right.

I have also seen this but cannot get this to work either [WCF message body showing <s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body> after modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106196/wcf-message-body-showing-sbody-stream-sbody-after-modification)

thanks

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a message using the CreateMessage(XmlReader, Int32, MessageVersion) method, you can use the GetBody method to read the body of the message.

For more information about CreateMessage,Please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.message.createmessage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_ServiceModel_Channels_Message_CreateMessage_System_Xml_XmlDictionaryReader_System_Int32_System_ServiceModel_Channels_MessageVersion_).

You can also get the message content through System.Xml.XmlWriter after getting the message:

```
        MessageBuffer buffer = newMessage.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        Message msg = buffer.CreateMessage();
        StringBuilder sbb = new StringBuilder();
        using (System.Xml.XmlWriter xx = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sbb))
        {
            msg.WriteMessage(xx);
            xx.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sbb);
```

The result of running:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is my Demo:

```
  public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:exsl=\"http://exslt.org/common\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">");
        sb.AppendLine("  <s:Header xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
        sb.AppendLine("    <To s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">https://localhost:44321/routingService</To>");
        sb.AppendLine("    <Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">getList</Action>");
        sb.AppendLine("  </s:Header>");
        sb.AppendLine("  <soapenv:Body>");
        sb.AppendLine("    <getList xmlns=\"http://xxx\" > ");
        sb.AppendLine("      <code>xxx</code>");
        sb.AppendLine("    </getList>");
        sb.AppendLine("  </soapenv:Body>");
        sb.AppendLine("</soapenv:Envelope>");
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
        var xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(xdr, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
        MessageBuffer messageBuffer = newMessage.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
        Message message = messageBuffer.CreateMessage();
        reply = message;
    }
```

[image]

In the gif, you can see that the client received the Message I customized on the server.

Comment: When I bring this into the application I still get the same result

Comment: "<soapenv:Body>... stream ...</soapenv:Body>" does not appear in the client, I call it by service reference.

Comment: Yes, but I am using it in a unit test, as detailed in the question

Comment: The same way I would any other unit test by creating the conditions for assertion, mocking what I would need to mock.  its just this being the issue